# Can't save as gltf

Tags: export, error

I am making the call to
`bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(filepath=output_file, use_selection=True, export_format='GLTF_SEPARATE')`

I tried the workaround here [Script to export gltf fails with 'Context' object has no attribute 'active_object'](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200616/script-to-export-gltf-fails-with-context-object-has-no-attribute-active-objec)

> AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'active_object'

Passing the context to the gltf function looks to be deprecated and I don't see how to override the context using temp_override.

I assume I am not setting up the context correctly as I tried to export as fbx and also got an exception.

Anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: Added a minimalistic script:

## Clear the scene

#bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile(use_empty=True)
#bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True)

## Load the GLTF file into an empty scene

bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath=GLTF_PATH)

out_path = utils.create_output_folder("xxxxx")

OUTPUT_FILE = out_path + "out.gltf"
bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(filepath=OUTPUT_FILE, use_selection=True, export_format='GLTF_SEPARATE')

If I include either of the lines to clear the scene I get the error. Wondering if there is a more correct way to clear Blender down to a state where it has no loaded data.

Comment: What Blender version are you using? Can you post a simple minimalistic script that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I'm using Blender 3.5.0. I have since noticed that I don't get this error if I don't use either one of these lines at the start of my script (will update the question with minimalistic version):
#bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile(use_empty=True)
#bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True)

Comment: I went with:
```lang-py
def clear_scene():
    # Remove all objects
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

    # Remove all materials
    for mat in bpy.data.materials:
        bpy.data.materials.remove(mat)

    # Remove all textures from the data blocks
    for tex in bpy.data.textures:
        bpy.data.textures.remove(tex)

    # Remove all images from the data blocks
    for img in bpy.data.images:
        bpy.data.images.remove(img)
```